# POM file in the case that junit tests are mixed with real source

Tags: java, maven, junit

I like to write classes together with their test code, e.g.,

```
  public class My {
    int zero() { return 0; }
    public static class TEST {
       @Test public void zeroTest() {
         assertEquals(0, zero());
       }
    }
  }
```

This is quite different than the usual maven assumptions

1. Test classes are not in a separate file, and certainly not in a separate folder.
2. Test methods may take  any name.
3. Test classes may take any name.

It would be really nice if I could have taught Maven this convention, so that in the compile stage, it would compile all code, including test code,
and in the test stage, it would just run junit against all code, which will lead to it picking only methods labeled with @Test.

Can this be done?

Comment: But then your test classes can be accessed in production code; and even if you make sure that they're not, you still have to carry the extra bloat of literally unused test code in your production code jars. Why do you want that?

Comment: It'd be a lot of work. Unrelated, but this seems like a convention that would lead to massive file bloat, less readability, harder packaging, etc. I can't come up with any good reasons to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to remove such classes automatically? All .class files that have @ Test methods can be eliminated.
It should be a tool's job to separate @ Test and other meta code from production code, not the programmer's.

Comment: If you test code is in the class as you production code there is no way to spearate that. You could create a tool which will filter out the byte code from the class files...But i don't see any advantage of this approach?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you do if you had to use a testing framework that required your test-cases to extend a base class instead of using annotations, such as `TestCase` in JUnit 3?

Comment: @Morfic: You do not need to mess with the byte code. Inner classes are placed in different .class files, so there  is no issue here. `static` inner classes can extend an external test base class

Comment: You're right, apologies, I totally missed the inner class definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid Maven favors [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) (that's their motto). So if you don't want to follow their convention, you will have a hard time doing so, as it's hard-wired in the way Maven works.

Maybe you could look into other build tools like Gradle that are less prone to conventions.